# Type the first/second/third parameter of a list

Tags: java, tuples

I was thinking of using a List as a tuple, I want do something like:

```
t.done(null, List.of(true, "some string");
```

is there a way to type the List, so that the first element must be a boolean and the second element must be a string?

Comment: You'll need a List<Object>/ List<AnyCommonSuperClass> for holding this mix-matched elements.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't look like there is a way to do it

Comment: From the javadocs, they(Collections) represent data items that form a natural group. You are against it with your requirement

Comment: Simply create a class for your needs and you’re done. This will save you from a lot of headache later on.

Comment: You can create a `List` of `Object` and then a `Class` of your type. So the List can accept any type as every class is being extended from `Object`

Answer (score 2):

No idea why you want to use a list for this. If you think a dedicated class is too much effort, you can try to use [`Triple<L,M,R>`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html) from Apache commons-lang:

```
Triple<Boolean, String, String> test = Triple.of(true, "some string", "another string");
```

Comment: It's for a library so I am looking for a built-in

Comment: You won’t find any builtin for this. Use a dedicated class then.

Comment: Yeah that's kinda lame that core Java doesn't have a Pair and Triple class or whatever

Comment: This is on purpose because this is not what OOP is about. Using `Pair` or even `Triple` should always be considered to be a code smell.

Comment: why is that exactly?